# Get a cell of dataset

Tags: c#, dataset

I am working with a windows application.

I load a dataset with dataadapter with fill 
`method.(objDataAdaptere.fill(objDataSet,"string"))`

Now I want to get a cell of this `dataset.(for example (row(0),cell(0)))`
How do I can do this?
Thanks.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The value? Assuming you mean "of the first table of the data-set", then:

```
    object value = dataSet.Tables[0].Rows[0][0];
```

but more specifically:

```
    object value = dataSet.Tables[tableIndex].Rows[rowIndex][colIndex];
```

Answer (score 1):

```
ds.Tables(0).Rows(0).ItemArray(0)
```

Where ItemArray Contains values like cell in gridView

Comment: ds.Tables[0].Rows[0][0] ought to do it without the creation of an ItemArray.

Comment: Since this is tagged C#, there is no way that `Tables(0).Rows(0).ItemArray(0)` is going to compile